# Cycling through Keys in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, cycle

So I need to define some function in python that will print each dictionary key with each value separately. Everything is an Airport Code, so the output, for example, should look like "There is a direct flight from ORD to JFK." And I need to print that for every direct flight from every airport.

The following is an example input

```
{"ORD" : ["JFK", "LAX", "SFO"],
"CID" : ["DEN", "ORD"],
"DEN" : ["CID", "SFO"],
"JFK" : ["LAX"],
"LAX" : ["ORD"],
"SFO" : []}
```

My function is

```
def printAllDirectFlights(flightGraph):
    x = len(flightGraph)
    y = 0
    while y < x:
        n = len(flightGraph[y])
        z = 0
        while z < n:
            print("There is a direct flight from",flightGraph[y],"to",flightGraph[y][z],".")
```

I thought this would work, but obviously I'm wrong. How do I cycle through the keys? I know that if I were, for example to write

```
print(flightGraph["ORD"][0])
```

then I would receive JFK as an output, but how do I go about cycling through the keys of a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Use `items()`:

```
for k,v in flightGraph.items():
    for c in v:
        print("There is a direct flight from " + k + " to " + c)


There is a direct flight from ORD to JFK
There is a direct flight from ORD to LAX
There is a direct flight from ORD to SFO
There is a direct flight from CID to DEN
There is a direct flight from CID to ORD
There is a direct flight from JFK to LAX
There is a direct flight from DEN to CID
There is a direct flight from DEN to SFO
There is a direct flight from LAX to ORD
```

Use `sorted(flightGraph.items())` if you want the first cities to be in alphabetical order:

```
for k,v in sorted(flightGraph.items()):
        for c in v:
            print("There is a direct flight from " + k + " to " + c)

There is a direct flight from CID to DEN
There is a direct flight from CID to ORD
There is a direct flight from DEN to CID
There is a direct flight from DEN to SFO
There is a direct flight from JFK to LAX
There is a direct flight from LAX to ORD
There is a direct flight from ORD to JFK
There is a direct flight from ORD to LAX
There is a direct flight from ORD to SFO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys in a dictionary `d` by doing `for key in d:` (which is equivalent to `for key in d.keys()`. Example below:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
for key in d:
    print key
```

Will print:

```
a
b
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I modified the code so d= flightGraph. And my first loop is for key in d. When I try to run it, though, I get, in this order. LAX
CID
SFO
ORD
JFK
LAX
SFO
DEN
ORD, why is the order seemingly random?

Answer (score 0):

If the length of keys can be more than 1 as a more general way, you can loop over the product of the keys with their relative values and get all the pairs:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for k, v in the_dict.items():
...     for i, j in product((k,), v):
...        print("There is a direct flight from {} to {}".format(i, j))
... 
There is a direct flight from JFK to LAX
There is a direct flight from CID to DEN
There is a direct flight from CID to ORD
There is a direct flight from LAX to ORD
There is a direct flight from DEN to CID
There is a direct flight from DEN to SFO
There is a direct flight from ORD to JFK
There is a direct flight from ORD to LAX
There is a direct flight from ORD to SFO
```

Note that while `dict.items` doesn't give you an ordered result, if you want to get an order as your input order you better to use an `OrderedDict` from `collection` module for preserving your key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!